# How to implment Marker and Markers Resolution for Editor in Eclipse RCP

Tags: marker

I need a tutorial which speaks about marker and marker resolution implementation in eclipse RCP. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try google. Recommendations are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to show you have done some research on the subject. Stackoverflow would help you when you get into difficulties in your research.

That said, I found these sites quite helpful.

- [eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_markerresolution.htm)
- [marker and annotations tutorial by Zoltán Ujhelyi](http://cubussapiens.hu/2011/05/custom-markers-and-annotations-the-bright-side-of-eclipse/)